# How to connect session variables to logged in user in Django?

Tags: django, session, cart, anonymous

I see that in e-commerce websites a visitor can add products to cart but while checkout he can log in and continue shopping without the session variables getting lost. For example, I add two items in cart and then I log in and add the third item. I guess it can be done with session so I made the following view for adding to cart:

```
def AddToBag(request, upc):
    if request.method == "GET":
        item = Item.objects.get(upc=upc)
        amount = 1
        price = Item.objects.filter(id=item.id).values('mrp')[0]['mrp']
        net = amount * price
        session_id = request.session.session_key
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            b, created = Bag.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, upc=upc, defaults={'item': item, 'qty': amount, 'price': price, 'net': net, 'session_id': session_id})
            if created:
                pass
            else:
                amount = Bag.objects.filter(user=request.user, upc=upc).values('qty')[0]['qty'] + 1
                net = amount * price
                Bag.objects.filter(upc=upc).update(qty=amount, net=net)
            total_items = Bag.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
            total_price = Bag.objects.filter(user=request.user).aggregate(Sum('net'))['net__sum']
        else:
            b, created = Bag.objects.get_or_create(user=User.objects.get(username='AnonymousUser'), upc=upc, defaults={'item': item, 'qty': amount, 'price': price, 'net': net, 'session_id': session_id})
            if created:
                pass
            else:
                amount = Bag.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username='AnonymousUser'), upc=upc).values('qty')[0]['qty'] + 1
                net = amount * price
                Bag.objects.filter(upc=upc).update(qty=amount, net=net)
            total_items = Bag.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username='AnonymousUser')).count()
            total_price = Bag.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username='AnonymousUser')).aggregate(Sum('net'))['net__sum']
    return render(request, "alpha/add-to-bag.html", {'total_items': total_items, 'total_price': total_price})
```

What I have noticed is that if I browse as `AnonymousUser` adding items to cart does not save the `session_key`, so when I log in all the items are gone and I have to start adding items all over again. If I log out again, the items added before logging in are still there.

What I want is that users can add items to cart while Anonymous, if they decide to log in, those items get transferred to their cart after loggin in. If they log out again and become anonymous visitor, they can lose the items as they have been transferred to their user cart. How can I do this?

**Update:** I have been able to create session id before a user logs in and save that to `session_id` field. However, the session IDs are different before and after login, how can the application understand if it is the same user?

Answer (score 0):

You must catch moment when user logs in, and copy basket into new session. For example, create your own login view, save basket from session before authentication and copy it into new session after authentication.

Another approach is to save basket (or basket ID) in user cookies.